# MS Graph API - List Secure Score is returning no data

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, securitycenter

I am trying to use [MS Graph Security API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-list-securescores?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get Secure Score data from my newly created tenant. The tenant has been created on 16th July i.e. 5 days back. I can see the Secure Score within Security Center but there is no Identity related secure like Number of admins has to be less than 3, more than 1 etc.

If I try and use [MS Graph Security API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-list-securescores?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) (List Secure Score), it is not returning any data.

> {
> "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Security/secureScores",
> "value": [] }

On the [Secure Score Portal](https://security.microsoft.com/securescorepreview?viewid=overview), it is giving me the below message

> "Microsoft is calculating your Secure Score, which usually takes 2-4
> days from when your tenant was created. Please check back later."

I have below questions if someone can help please -

1. How do I enforce a secure score calculation for default security controls. I have enabled the default security controls today. ASC Defaults are enabled by default and I have added a few more Azure policies on top of it. My primary goal is to view the control scores using MS Graph Security API.
2. How can i add more security controls to be added as part of secure score or is it done by default for all Azure Policies.

Sorry, If these are very basic questions but I tried looking for documentation but could not find any on this.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Secure Score Graph API and the Secure Score Portal both leverage the same infrastructure, so when one is returning data, the other should as well. In some cases the "2-4 days" can be MUCH longer. We are working on streamlining this.

WRT your two questions, you mention ASC (Azure Security Center) and Azure several times. I take it that you are interested in the [Azure Secure Score](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/secure-score-security-controls).  This is a separate product from [Microsoft Secure Score](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/mtp/microsoft-secure-score?view=o365-worldwide). Currently ASC controls are not a part of Microsoft Secure Score. The MS Graph API you reference does not currently include ASC controls.

Comment: Thanks, took me a while but I realized that basically these 2 are different products. Since graph is supposed to be one stop solution for all MS products, would'nt it will be better of MS graph to also provide the details about azure secure score and security controls. Or Microsoft Secure Score is primarily for Office 365 products and not Azure. To take an example - "Designate more than one global admin" is an MS security control, isn't this related to admins in Azure AD. Once again, sorry if this is a very basic question.